# How to add an email to a specific folder to all mailboxes in Exchange 2013/Office365?

Tags: microsoft-office, powershell, office365, exchange-2013

I know I can use PowerShell to add a custom folder to all user mailboxes in the Exchange 2013/Office 365 organization. I also want to add specific emails to the newly created custom folder in all mailboxes.  How can I do this using PowerShell?

Comment: Not sure if Powershell works with EWS, but if you used c# you could for sure use it. if you have a account with permission to all mailboxes you could use EWS to place a message in everyones mailbox  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/12/02/learn-to-use-the-exchange-web-services-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an email address to a folder.

If you want to go forward with the above you need to assign an inbox rule and you can use the `New-InboxRule` CmdLet to do that. You need to have proper rights to access the mailbox to run that command.  **WARNING**:  If the user has any client side rules - those will be removed once you assign your rules.

You could also just provide users with instructions on how to create the rule themselves.

Other options I can think of:

- Use a separate mailbox and grant users rights to that
- Use Journaling or Transport rules to route to different mailbox (not
  folder)